# Integrating dialogflow to my simple HTML code using the <i frame/>

Tags: iframe, dialogflow-es, http-status-code-403, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Am trying to integrate the created dialogflow in my simple html using the iframe code but when i try to open it in the browser, **its display error "403. That’s an error.We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know."**

[this is the error image on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mpQM.png)

[This is the code i inserted in my html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTDTL.png) .

So my question is What could be the cause of this problem?

I was expecting my dialogflow chatbot to display in my browser

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check your Dialogflow Settings:

Ensure that your Dialogflow agent is correctly configured and that it is accessible to the right users.

Make sure the agent is enabled.
Check the agent's settings to ensure it's set up to be publicly accessible or accessible to your intended users.
Verify the agent's environment (e.g., development or production) and ensure that you're using the correct environment in your iframe code.